# Fill numpy array by indexing with 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array of zeros `subbins`, and a 2d numpy array of indices into it `combos`. For example

```
p = 4
combos = np.asarray(list(itertools.combinations(range(p),3)))
subbins = np.zeros(shape=(len(combos),p))
```

The arrays look like this

```
combos = [[0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [0 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
subbins = [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

How can I use `combos` to index into `subbins` and assign values without iterating - as *pythonic* as possible? I.e. the output I want is this:

```
output = [[1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html):

```
np.put_along_axis(subbins, combos, 1, axis=1)
```

---

```
print(subbins)
array([[1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```